# How do I use data from server/database for display of view controller before view controller is loaded

Tags: json, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I want to load/use json data for the display of our view controller before loading the view when we run the simulation on swift because our view’s table is dependent on the json data that we’re receiving from the server. However, when we use the code below, it doesn't display the correct data onto the screen. We are successful in being able to retrieve the data from our HTTP request to the server but aren't able to use to it for our view display.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cam1N.png)

Comment: add code as text not image

Comment: Copy/paste code, not screenshot only.? `print(friendliest.result)` => `print("Inside closure: \(friendliest.result)")` & `print(nameArray)` => `print("NameArray: \(nameArray)")`. Which one do you think will be printed first? Yes it's async. Mook for "Swift + Async + Closure", but in a nutshell, you'll get the data after sometime, when it's done, reload the tableView in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the table inside the completion

```
self.namesArray = friendList.result
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tblView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Do we do this in viewDidLoad()?

Comment: below this line `self.namesArray = friendList.result` in your current code

Comment: @NatalieWang If you did had copy/paste your code instead of screenshot, I'm sure Sh_Khan would have just copy/paste the full interesting part to make you understand where to write it, but since it's a screenshot, it's understandable to not retape it. Once reason why copy/paste over screenshot (and referencing/Search)

Comment: in addition to what @Larme said text is used by search engines when other ops search for similar problems where images won't fit for this